# ngrx/store organization for multiple parallel updates to an object array

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a list of book cards on the UI in a collapsed view, when a book card is clicked (i.e expanded), we dispatch 2 more calls to the backend to fetch more data against on the book using the book Id - say GET /bookSummary and GET /bookTranslations. To manage the state of the book list I have:

```
interface bookState {
  books: IBook[];
  isRequesting: boolean;
  error: IError
}
```

I am struggling to come up with a store organization to house the state of the additional 2 calls. The biggest issue is that the user can click to expand multiple book cards at the same time and so each expansion needs to be tracked independently. Essentially creating a dynamic list of states for each of the 2 calls:

```
interface bookSummaryState {
  bookId: string;
  summary: ISummary;
  isRequesting: boolean;
  error: IError
}

interface bookTranslationsState {
  bookId: string;
  translations: Translations[];
  isRequesting: boolean;
  error: IError
}
```

I am not sure where and how to house the fact that I need multiple instances of bookTranslationsState and bookSummaryState at the same time.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing:

```
interface overallBookState {
  booksSummaryState: {
    [key: string]: bookSummaryState; 
  },
  booksTranslationState: {
    [key: string]: bookTranslationsState;
  }
}
```

This should make the object look something like this:

```
{
  booksSummaryState: {
    '1': {
        bookId: '1',
        summary: ...
        isRequesting: false,
        error: ....
     },
    '2': {
        bookId: '2',
        summary: ....
        isRequesting: false,
        error: ....
     }
  },
  booksTranslationState: {
    '1': {
      bookId: '1',
      translations: ....
      isRequesting: false,
      error: ...
    }, 
    '2': {
       bookId: '2',
       translations: ....
       isRequesting: fasle,
       error: ....
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can read from that state which one was clicked and read the values from the book id.